# NSFetchedResultController multiple limit and sort

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Hi i have a problem my Table in core data similar like This

```
+-----------------------+
|person                 |
+-----------------------+
|name                   |
|address                |
|birthDate              |
|gender                 |
+-----------------------+
```

In my FetchedResultController i fetch this into two section by its Gender `Male` and `Female`.
And the problem is i want the `Male` section sort by its `birthDate` and Limit only 5 Rows, in `Female` section i want sort it by its `name` and No Limit.

Can i done that in One FetchedResultController or i need 2 FetchedResultController. or if there is another way to done that let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Show your code please !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with one `NSFetchedResultController` if you define your own sort method.  It would be something like:

```
- (NSString *) sortBy
{ return (Male == self.gender ? self.birthDate : self.name); }
```

and then provide `sortBy` in the configuration of the controller.  Note, as @Martin R noted, you may not be able to use an Objective-C method for sorting; if not, then define another attribute 'sortOrder' and compute it on object creation.

As for the limit, not sure, but perhaps it could be achieved in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`  Apple gives this example:

```
- (NSInteger) tableView: (UITableView *) table 
  numberOfRowsInSection: (NSInteger) section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = 
      [[<#Fetched results controller#> sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}
```

Perhaps you could return '3' when the section is the 'Male' section.

Comment: For a sort descriptor in a (SQLite based) Core Data fetch request, you can use only *persistent attributes*. Objective-C based sort methods do not work.

Comment: Thanks for answer my question, but how i can Limit the `Male` only 3 Rows but no Limit in `Female`. Thanks.

Comment: See edits.  I addressed @MartinR's comment and provided an approach to your limit of '3'.